# Splitting a Spark flatmap

Tags: apache-spark

I have a process in Spark that I want to distribute across a number of nodes in my cluster:

```scala
        val fetchedRdd = rdd.map(r => (r.getDedupeId, r))
        .groupByKey(100)
        .flatMap({ case (grp, rs) => new FairFetcher(job, rs.iterator, localFetchDelay,
          FetchFunction, ParseFunction, OutLinkFilterFunction, StatusUpdateSolrTransformer).toSeq })
        .persist()
```

The FairFetcher RDD has no real content in it until its been executed, all the business logic is really within it.

When this is finally evaluated, I see my 100 partitions, but all of the effort ends up in 1 task on 1 node. I can't come up with a way to distribute this work across the cluster.

What do I need to do differently, so that the flatMap ends up across the nodes with the result joined at the end?

```scala
class RunCrawl extends Serializable{
  def mapCrawl(x: Iterator[(String, Iterable[Resource])], job: SparklerJob): Iterator[CrawlData] = {
    val m = 1000
    x.flatMap({case (grp, rs) => new FairFetcher(job, rs.iterator, m,
      FetchFunction, ParseFunction, OutLinkFilterFunction, StatusUpdateSolrTransformer)})
  }

  def runCrawl(f: RDD[(String, Iterable[Resource])], job: SparklerJob): RDD[CrawlData] = {
    f.mapPartitions( x => mapCrawl(x, job))
  }
}
```

I did try a similar idea, but using the mapPartitions function, but it ends up doing the same.

I'm clearly missing something important about how Spark allocates its work.